# Vim syntax highlighting: how to stop the automatic underlining of <a href=..>?

Tags: vim, html

When I type a HTML element a, there is always a underline. I want to stop this, but do not know how?

I'm talking about the vim syntax highlight.

Comment: Are you talking about syntax highlighting in vim or styling html?

Comment: Isn't it also clickable in Vim, to open the link in a browser? (Hence: maybe it's not just about how it's displayed?)

Comment: @Arjan: `vim`'s syntax highlighting displays the anchor text (content of the `<a>` tag) in underline.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a copy of the `html.vim` syntax highlighting definition.

```
mkdir -p ~/.vim/syntax
cp /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/html.vim ~/.vim/syntax/
# "vim72" for version 7.2
vim ~/.vim/syntax/html.vim
```

Find this line: *(should be around line 248)*

```
    HtmlHiLink htmlLink                    Underlined
```

To disable styling completely, comment out the line (prefix with a `"` *double-quote*).

To change appearance, replace the `Underlined` part with a different highlight definition (such as `htmlBold`, or define your own: there are several examples just below that line).

Comment: Or better yet, just put something like "highlight link htmlLink text" in: ~/.vim/after/syntax/html.vim -- that way you won't have to worry about what happens when a new version of the default html.vim comes out.